# pmset default settings

Tags: macos, power-management

I was using this guide and changed a lot of pmset settings duo of FileVault2

https://github.com/drduh/macOS-Security-and-Privacy-Guide#full-disk-encryption

Is there any option to restore the factory defaults?

Answer (score 1):

Open System Preferences → Energy Saver and choose Restore Defaults.

Answer (score 0):

mset can modify the values of any of the power management settings defined below. You may specify one or more setting & value pairs on the command-line invocation of pmset. The −a, −b, −c, −u flags determine whether the settings apply to battery ( −b ), charger (wall power) ( −c ), UPS ( −u ) or all ( −a ).

Use a minutes argument of 0 to set the idle time to never for sleep disksleep and displaysleep.
https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset.html you can use this link to for more setting details.